# JSF 2.1 along with JSP/Tiles in a Spring 3.1 MVC Project

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, facelets, tiles

I have a Spring 3.1 MVC application with JSP as the primary View technology, Apache Tiles for page templating, jQuery etc. I recently had a requirement which requires complicated UI processing which I feel JSF/Facelets would be a better choice.

The existing application works in this flow

```
HttpRequest > Spring MVC DispatcherServlet > Tiles > JSP
```

I'm talking about couple JSF pages here among 50+ JSP pages. I want to keep the existing tiles template also.

What are my options here to use JSF along with other JSF pages in this application?

Is there any provision available where the Spring MVC dispatcher Servlet delegates the requests to a JSF Backing Bean? Expected flow would be something like:

```
HttpRequest > Spring MVC DispatcherServlet > Tiles > JSF/BackingBean
```

Comment: should be possible as facesServlet can process jsf/non-jsf requests.

Comment: I'm thinking the same way. Also I could see MyFaces has a direct support for Tiles. Let's see if anybody has done this already.